# How do you test a null that a single regression line adequately describes the data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

I was wondering how you would test the null that a single regression line adequate describes the data, i.e.

$H_A: $ two parallel lines needed (additional indicator variable here)

Comparing summary outputs from both I can see that with two lines, you get a higher F-stat, lower respective p-value, and higher Adjusted-$
R^2$, but I'm not sure what to test for in this case.

All help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how would you interpret the predicted results of two parallel regression lines?

Comment: @TilefishPoele I assume he means a linear regression model with one continuous covariate and one categorical covariate with 2 levels.

Comment: @AndyKreek yes that's what I mean and I found the solution! It involves calculating (SS of the full model, subtracting it SS of the reduced model / predictors tested) / (SSE full / n-k-1)

Answer (score 2):

In a linear regression setting, "two parallel lines" is equivalent to $E(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_c c + \beta_x x$ where $x$ is a continuous covariate (hence the line) and $c$ is a binary indicator (hence 2 parallel lines with intercepts depending on whether $c=1$ or $c=0$).

So, *your* test is equivalent to the test $H_0:$ $\beta_c= 0$ vs. $H_A:$ $\beta_c \neq 0$.

In fact, the $p$-value in standard regression output for the coefficient $\beta_c$ is exactly the $p$-value for this test.

So if the $p$-value for $\beta_c$ is smaller some threshold, typically 0.05, then you can conclude that there is strong evidence in your data to reject $H_0$. In this case, "2 parallel lines" would describe your data better than one.

(Note, simply having a smaller $p$-value for your $F$ test doesn't indicate that the coefficient $\beta_c \neq 0$. The $p$-value for the overall $F$ test indicates the degree to which there is evidence in your data that *any* $\beta$ in the model is non-zero. You can, however, compare $F$ statistics for 2 nested models, e.g. models with and without the variable $c$. In this case, that would be  equivalent to above test.)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer my prof. was looking for in the textbook:

[image: Answer]